# Why is there only NA values when I'm extracting data from raster layer to the shapefile dataframe?

Tags: r, raster, shapefile, r-raster

I'm trying to use exactextract to extract the mean of nightlight data from Rwanda to the shapefile of Rwanda's boundaries. Here are my codes:

```
night_light1 <- raster(here("Night Lights Data", "path.tif"),1)
rwa_sector <- st_read(dsn = here("Population Density Map","rwa_sector", "Sector.shp"))
```

I am able to separately plot `night_light1` and `rwa_sector`.

I have aligned the extent and crs of these two datasets.

But when I'm using this code:

```
rwa_sector$nightlight <- exact_extract(night_light1,rwa_sector,'mean')
```

to extract a mean for each sector, it doesn't seem to work and the nightlight column only have NA values.

Not sure which step was wrong. Could anybody help？ Thank you.

Here are my codes:

```
night_light1 <- raster(here("Night Lights Data", "path.tif"),1)
rwa_sector <- st_read(dsn = here("Population Density Map","rwa_sector", "Sector.shp"))
```

I am able to separately plot `night_light1` and `rwa_sector`.

I have aligned the extent and crs of these two datasets.

But when I'm using this code:

```
rwa_sector$nightlight <- exact_extract(night_light1,rwa_sector,'mean')
```

to extract a mean for each sector, it doesn't seem to work and the nightlight column only have NA values.

Not sure which step was wrong. Could anybody help？ Thank you.